# Trying to Run RT(Request Tracker) on a mail Server (Zimbra), problems with web server?

Tags: centos, zimbra, request-tracker

I have installed `zimbra` and I am using it as my mail server.
However I wanted to also install `request tracker`, so that the server could be used for admin and my other server purely as a web server.

Zimbra is working 100%, however when I install `httpd` the `zimbra` front end disappears and is replaced by the default `apache httpd` page.

I am using `centOS 6 64 bit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. Zimbra is a complicated beast with lot of components and it should run on a dedicated server or VM.

For the specific problem: Obviously, you noticed that there is a conflict between Zimbras own web server and the one you installed. If you insist to continue with this, you would have to change ports for the Zimbra web server installation and then configure a reverse proxy in Apache to forward requests, e.g. to `http://example.com/zimbra` to the altered port of the Zimbra web server.

Again: Don't do this. There is also no need if you have another server as a web server. RT plays nicely with most web servers and it's easy to get the mail into  it from another server - there is no need to put it on the same host as the mail server.